# Group array data by name

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, pure-js

I'm trying to develop an array with expertise 'Transport' containing each sector and the text assigned to them.

This is what I have:

```
    - Healthcare
    -- Data-driven insights to improve healthcare
    -- Novel data mining and visualisation
    -- Human-centred augmented and virtual realities

    - Energy
    -- Urban Analytics
    -- Understanding patterns of consumer behaviour
    -- Optimising energy systems
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
    - expertise (e.g Transport)

    -- sector (e.g Data)
    --- text (e.g Urban Analytics)
    --- text (e.g Understanding patterns of consumer behaviour)
    --- text (e.g Human-centred augmented and virtual realities)

    -- sector (e.g Engineering)
    --- text (e.g Optimising energy systems)
    --- text (e.g High speed rail and system integration innovation)
    --- text (e.g Human-centred robotic and autonomous systems)
    --- text (e.g Surface engineering across the length scales)

    -- sector (e.g Environment)
    --- text (e.g Europe’s leading city simulation capability)

    - expertise
    -- sector
    --- text
```

Here's the code I'm using at the moment if anyone is able to help I would highly appreciate it.

```js
var items = [{
    "item": {
      "id": 0,
      "sector": 'Data',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare"],
      "text": "Data-driven insights to improve healthcare"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 1,
      "sector": 'Data',
      "expertise": ["Energy", "Transport", "Cities"],
      "text": "Urban Analytics"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 2,
      "sector": 'Data',
      "expertise": ["Energy", "Transport", "Consumer"],
      "text": "Understanding patterns of consumer behaviour"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 3,
      "sector": 'Data',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare", "Consumer"],
      "text": "Novel data mining and visualisation"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 4,
      "sector": 'Data',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare", "Transport", "Consumer"],
      "text": "Human-centred augmented and virtual realities"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 5,
      "sector": 'Healthcare',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare"],
      "text": "Medical technology innovation, translation and convergence"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 6,
      "sector": 'Healthcare',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare"],
      "text": "Understanding cardio metabolic disease"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 7,
      "sector": 'Healthcare',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare"],
      "text": "Improving early cancer diagnosis and treatment"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 8,
      "sector": 'Healthcare',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare", "Pharmaceuticals"],
      "text": "Understanding life in molecular detail"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 9,
      "sector": 'Healthcare',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare"],
      "text": "Evidencing treatment through clinical trials"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 10,
      "sector": 'Engineering',
      "expertise": ["Energy", "Transport"],
      "text": "Optimising energy systems"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 11,
      "sector": 'Engineering',
      "expertise": ["Energy"],
      "text": "Enhancing petroleum recovery"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 12,
      "sector": 'Engineering',
      "expertise": ["Transport"],
      "text": "High speed rail and system integration innovation"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 13,
      "sector": 'Engineering',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare", "Electronics"],
      "text": "Terahertz frequency electronic and photonic devices"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 14,
      "sector": 'Engineering',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare", "Transport", "Manufacturing"],
      "text": "Human-centred robotic and autonomous systems"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 15,
      "sector": 'Engineering',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare", "Energy", "Transport", "Manufacturing"],
      "text": "Surface engineering across the length scales"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 16,
      "sector": 'Engineering',
      "expertise": ["Pharmaceuticals", "Manufacturing"],
      "text": "Chemical and process engineering from molecule to product"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 17,
      "sector": 'Engineering',
      "expertise": ["Pharmaceuticals"],
      "text": "Bionanotechnology for disease diagnosis, treatment and prevention"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 18,
      "sector": 'Engineering',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare", "Pharmaceuticals", "Electronics", "Manufacturing"],
      "text": "Engineering materials at the atomic level"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 19,
      "sector": 'Environment',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare", "Environment & Food"],
      "text": "Addressing global challenges in food security"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 20,
      "sector": 'Environment',
      "expertise": ["Healthcare", "Environment & Food"],
      "text": "Interdisciplinary approaches to tackling major water issues"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 21,
      "sector": 'Environment',
      "expertise": ["Cities"],
      "text": "Designing cities of the future"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 22,
      "sector": 'Environment',
      "expertise": ["Transport", "Cities"],
      "text": "Europe’s leading city simulation capability"
    }
  },
  {
    "item": {
      "id": 23,
      "sector": 'Environment',
      "expertise": ["Environment & Food"],
      "text": "Robust and timely climate solutions"
    }
  }
];

let expertise;
let res = items.reduce((acc, {
  item: {
    expertise,
    text
  }
}) => {
  expertise.forEach(x => acc[x] = [...(acc[x] || []), text]);
  return acc;
}, {});


Object.entries(res).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  console.log(k + "\n->" + v.join("\n->"));
});
```

Comment: Codepen: https://codepen.io/adamkwadsworth/pen/exzYxo?editors=0010

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Perhaps you could post the expected result in the form of code, and not in the form of a list with examples ?

Comment: You want two levels of grouping. You need to do it with two passes. First group everything by sector, then loop over each sector and group within it by expertise.

Comment: Is this what you are expecting: https://codepen.io/rakesh-makluri/pen/omLXBM?editors=0012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need one more level for the sectors:

```js
var items = [{"item": {"id": 0,"sector": 'Data',"expertise": ["Healthcare"],"text": "Data-driven insights to improve healthcare"}},{"item": {"id": 1,"sector": 'Data',"expertise": ["Energy", "Transport", "Cities"],"text": "Urban Analytics"}},{"item": {"id": 2,"sector": 'Data',"expertise": ["Energy", "Transport", "Consumer"],"text": "Understanding patterns of consumer behaviour"}},{"item": {"id": 3,"sector": 'Data',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Consumer"],"text": "Novel data mining and visualisation"}},{"item": {"id": 4,"sector": 'Data',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Transport", "Consumer"],"text": "Human-centred augmented and virtual realities"}},{"item": {"id": 5,"sector": 'Healthcare',"expertise": ["Healthcare"],"text": "Medical technology innovation, translation and convergence"}},{"item": {"id": 6,"sector": 'Healthcare',"expertise": ["Healthcare"],"text": "Understanding cardio metabolic disease"}},{"item": {"id": 7,"sector": 'Healthcare',"expertise": ["Healthcare"],"text": "Improving early cancer diagnosis and treatment"}},{"item": {"id": 8,"sector": 'Healthcare',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Pharmaceuticals"],"text": "Understanding life in molecular detail"}},{"item": {"id": 9,"sector": 'Healthcare',"expertise": ["Healthcare"],"text": "Evidencing treatment through clinical trials"}},{"item": {"id": 10,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Energy", "Transport"],"text": "Optimising energy systems"}},{"item": {"id": 11,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Energy"],"text": "Enhancing petroleum recovery"}},{"item": {"id": 12,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Transport"],"text": "High speed rail and system integration innovation"}},{"item": {"id": 13,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Electronics"],"text": "Terahertz frequency electronic and photonic devices"}},{"item": {"id": 14,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Transport", "Manufacturing"],"text": "Human-centred robotic and autonomous systems"}},{"item": {"id": 15,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Energy", "Transport", "Manufacturing"],"text": "Surface engineering across the length scales"}},{"item": {"id": 16,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Pharmaceuticals", "Manufacturing"],"text": "Chemical and process engineering from molecule to product"}},{"item": {"id": 17,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Pharmaceuticals"],"text": "Bionanotechnology for disease diagnosis, treatment and prevention"}},{"item": {"id": 18,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Pharmaceuticals", "Electronics", "Manufacturing"],"text": "Engineering materials at the atomic level"}},{"item": {"id": 19,"sector": 'Environment',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Environment & Food"],"text": "Addressing global challenges in food security"}},{"item": {"id": 20,"sector": 'Environment',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Environment & Food"],"text": "Interdisciplinary approaches to tackling major water issues"}},{"item": {"id": 21,"sector": 'Environment',"expertise": ["Cities"],"text": "Designing cities of the future"}},{"item": {"id": 22,"sector": 'Environment',"expertise": ["Transport", "Cities"],"text": "Europe’s leading city simulation capability"}},{"item": {"id": 23,"sector": 'Environment',"expertise": ["Environment & Food"],"text": "Robust and timely climate solutions"}}];

const res = items.reduce((acc, {item: {sector, expertise, text}}) => {
    expertise.forEach(exp => {
        acc[exp] = acc[exp] || {};
        acc[exp][sector] = [...(acc[exp][sector] || []), text];
    });
    return acc;
}, {});

Object.entries(res).forEach(([exp, sectors]) => {
    console.log("- " + exp);
    Object.entries(sectors).forEach(([sector, texts]) => {
        console.log("-- " + sector + "\n--- " + texts.join("\n--- "));
    });
});
```

#### Explanation

In the `reduce` operation, the `sector` is also grabbed from the object. Just like in the original, the expertises are iterated over, but now the `acc` object becomes a two-level object instead of just one level. The first level properties are the expertises (`exp`). If such property does not exist yet, it gets an empty object as value:

```
        acc[exp] = acc[exp] || {};
```

The line that follows is much like you already had it: the next property level consists of the sectors, and for each sector an array of texts is maintained.

The second part of the code applies the same principle as you already had it, but again with an extra level. First the expertise properties are iterated over. They have objects as values, each having sector properties. The inner loop is then again much like you had it: for each sector the sector and associated text values are displayed.

Comment: Morning Trincot, I made a mistake within my description. I've updated now. Thank you.

Comment: I have added a second snippet with that order to my answer. It is the same principle.

Comment: Perfect, could I ask for explanation on how you got this to work. It'll help me with learning how to do this in future.

Comment: Added an explanation, but given that you already applied the used principles in your original code, there is not really any additional magic happening. Just the accumulator is now an object with 2 nested levels instead of 1.

Answer (score -1):

You can try following approach which is sort of generic:

#### Idea

- Create a function (*say A*) that prints:

  - Bullet, in this solution `-`
  - Key being used
  - value of this key in specific format.
- Also create a function (*say B*) that parses and returns formatted string for value.

  - For Array, it will use `Array.join`
  - For non-empty objects, it will use the same function you create above (*A*).
  - For non-empty literal values, it will return `value.toString()`
  - And for empty values, it will return a blank value.

---

- Both functions `A` and `B` denotes a lower/next level. Hence, you will have to add `-` or the bullet value to the existing bullet string.
- Since its a nested structure, you will have to clean string (*Remove extra `\n`s using `string.trim()`*) so that you do not get multiple new lines.
- Using these interlinked function will print in necessary format irrespective of depth.

```js
function isEmpty(value) {
  return value === null || value === undefined
}

function getValueString(v, preString) {
  preString = `\n${preString.trim()}-`;
  return Array.isArray(v) && (preString + v.join(preString)) ||
    typeof v === 'object' && nestedLevelToString(v, preString) ||
    isEmpty(v) && v.toString() ||
    '';
}

function nestedLevelToString(data, preString) {
  preString = preString || '-';
  let output = ''
  for (const key in data) {
    output += `${preString}${key}${getValueString(data[key], preString)}`;
  }
  return output;
}

var items = [{"item": {"id": 0,"sector": 'Data',"expertise": ["Healthcare"],"text": "Data-driven insights to improve healthcare"}},{"item": {"id": 1,"sector": 'Data',"expertise": ["Energy", "Transport", "Cities"],"text": "Urban Analytics"}},{"item": {"id": 2,"sector": 'Data',"expertise": ["Energy", "Transport", "Consumer"],"text": "Understanding patterns of consumer behaviour"}},{"item": {"id": 3,"sector": 'Data',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Consumer"],"text": "Novel data mining and visualisation"}},{"item": {"id": 4,"sector": 'Data',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Transport", "Consumer"],"text": "Human-centred augmented and virtual realities"}},{"item": {"id": 5,"sector": 'Healthcare',"expertise": ["Healthcare"],"text": "Medical technology innovation, translation and convergence"}},{"item": {"id": 6,"sector": 'Healthcare',"expertise": ["Healthcare"],"text": "Understanding cardio metabolic disease"}},{"item": {"id": 7,"sector": 'Healthcare',"expertise": ["Healthcare"],"text": "Improving early cancer diagnosis and treatment"}},{"item": {"id": 8,"sector": 'Healthcare',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Pharmaceuticals"],"text": "Understanding life in molecular detail"}},{"item": {"id": 9,"sector": 'Healthcare',"expertise": ["Healthcare"],"text": "Evidencing treatment through clinical trials"}},{"item": {"id": 10,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Energy", "Transport"],"text": "Optimising energy systems"}},{"item": {"id": 11,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Energy"],"text": "Enhancing petroleum recovery"}},{"item": {"id": 12,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Transport"],"text": "High speed rail and system integration innovation"}},{"item": {"id": 13,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Electronics"],"text": "Terahertz frequency electronic and photonic devices"}},{"item": {"id": 14,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Transport", "Manufacturing"],"text": "Human-centred robotic and autonomous systems"}},{"item": {"id": 15,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Energy", "Transport", "Manufacturing"],"text": "Surface engineering across the length scales"}},{"item": {"id": 16,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Pharmaceuticals", "Manufacturing"],"text": "Chemical and process engineering from molecule to product"}},{"item": {"id": 17,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Pharmaceuticals"],"text": "Bionanotechnology for disease diagnosis, treatment and prevention"}},{"item": {"id": 18,"sector": 'Engineering',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Pharmaceuticals", "Electronics", "Manufacturing"],"text": "Engineering materials at the atomic level"}},{"item": {"id": 19,"sector": 'Environment',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Environment & Food"],"text": "Addressing global challenges in food security"}},{"item": {"id": 20,"sector": 'Environment',"expertise": ["Healthcare", "Environment & Food"],"text": "Interdisciplinary approaches to tackling major water issues"}},{"item": {"id": 21,"sector": 'Environment',"expertise": ["Cities"],"text": "Designing cities of the future"}},{"item": {"id": 22,"sector": 'Environment',"expertise": ["Transport", "Cities"],"text": "Europe’s leading city simulation capability"}},{"item": {"id": 23,"sector": 'Environment',"expertise": ["Environment & Food"],"text": "Robust and timely climate solutions"}}];


let expertise;
const res = {};
res['sector'] = items.reduce((acc, {
  item: {
    expertise,
    text
  }
}) => {
  expertise.forEach(x => acc[x] = [...(acc[x] || []), text]);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(nestedLevelToString(res));
```